# Translating sentences to propositional calculus formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following exercise which I found in my text book.

*Dave invites his friends to his wedding and gets the following responses.*

1. *If Arnold does not come, then Bianca doesn't want to come either.*
2. *At least one of the siblings Carla and Daniel come*
3. *Either Arnold or Elisa come, but not both*
4. *Either Elisa and Daniel come, or both do not come*
5. *If Carla comes, then Daniel and Bianca also come.*

*Formalize the sentences in propositional calculus and find out who comes to the wedding.*

**My solutions looks as follows.**

Let $X_i$ be a variable with $i \in \{(A)rnold,(B)ianca,(C)arla,(D)aniel,(E)lisa\}$ and $I(X_i)=1$ iff i comes to the wedding.

1. $\lnot X_A \to \lnot X_B$
2. $X_C \lor X_D$
3. $(\lnot X_A \land X_E) \lor (X_A \land \lnot X_E)$
4. $X_E \land X_D$
5. $X_C \to (X_D \land X_B)$

Is this correct? And how do I proceed to find out who comes the wedding? My idea was to find an interpretation I such that $I \vDash (\lnot X_A \to \lnot X_B) \land (X_C \lor X_D) \land ((\lnot X_A \land X_E) \lor (X_A \land \lnot X_E)) \land (X_E \land X_D) \land (X_C \to (X_D \land X_B))$. But I constructed the truth table and found out that the formula is unsatisfiable. What is wrong here?

Comment: Why unsatisfiable ? with an assignment $v$ such that: $v(A)=v(B)=v(C)=$ **F** and $v(D)=v(E)=$ **T** all the premises are satisfied.

Comment: If so, the conclusion is: Daniel and Elisa come to the wedding.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake in my evaluation. I will check that. Are the formulas 1-5 correct?

Comment: I think 4. should be $X_E \iff X_D$, since it allows both $X_E$ and $X_D$ to be false.

Comment: I agree with Mauro and I think this is the only solution. I agree with gandalf61 too although a solution with $v(D)=v(E)=F$ does not seem to exist. This would make $v(C) = T$ (by 2) and condition 5 would then evaluate to $T \rightarrow F$ which is not possible.

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes, I think you are correct, condition 4 should be $X_E \iff X_D$. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulAljabar So does that mean that with the change to condition 4, condition 5 as formulated above is also not correct?

Comment: No, I think condition 5 is correct as it is formulated above.

Comment: Ok, with the change to condition 4 and the interpretation I with $I(A) = I(B) = I(C) = F,I(D) = I(E) = T$ all premises are satisfied.